# export nested XML from Google Sheet

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets and installed the add-on "Export Sheet Data". How do I have to design the sheet and what settings do I have to choose in the sidebar, in order to get a 3 level nested xml output, like:

```
<root>
 <fruit>
  <description>
   <en>Some text</en>
   <de>etwas text</de>
   <es>poco texto</es>
  </description>
 </fruit>
</root>
```

I only seem to achive this if I include the last level as text in the field content, using a sheet like:

```
root   description          description           description  
fruit  <en>Some text</en>   <de>etwas text</de>   <es>poco texto</es>
```